# Sencha Touch Cordova iOS app takes more than 20 seconds to load and shuts down

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

My sencha touch cordova app which runs fine on all android devices and iPhones as well except for iPhone 6s. When I build and deploy the app on iPhone 6 and tap on it to start, I see the splash screen for 20 seconds and ios shuts it down since it takes more than 20 seconds to load. Weird thing is the same .ipa works fine on iPhone 6 which has the same ios version and built the exact same way. Any pointers on how I can debug whats going wrong with the app on this device particularly?
More details about my app :

Sencha Touch version : 2.4.2
Cordova version on my machine : 6.1.1
iOS version of iPhone 6s : 9.3.2
using Terminal on Mac to build code using following commands :

```
sencha app build native

cordova build ios --device
```

This gives me the ipa file which I then install using iTunes on to the iPhone 6s.

Also it works fine in xcode simulator - only takes more than 20 seconds to load on a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this exactly worked but I converted the app from an universal app to a iphone only app in xcode build settings and archived the .ipa using xcode itself - deployed it using iTunes and it started working fine - did not do any changes to code or anywhere else.